# Business logic in Symfony 2/3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I cant understand where shoud be business logic.

For example: 
I shoud render  tag with some data from entity according to user role. 
If im using yii(dont hate me) framework, in view side it will be somethig like that:

```
<td>
    <?php if ($model->isEngineer()): ?>
         <?= $model->getEngineerData(); ?>
    <?php elseif ($model->isAdmin()): ?>
         <?= $model->getAdminData(); ?>
    <?php else? ?>
         <?= $model->getOtherData(); ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<td>
```

According to best Symfony Best Practices, I shoud't have  isEngineer, getEngineerData, etc methods inside Entity Class, also I shoud't calls any method from Model's side. So I have created some twig extension, but how to send variables(Objects/properties not only stings) from .html.twig to twig extension, or how to handle business logic?

Comment: Have a look to MVC architecture. The Controller take informations from model and show them to the view...

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851629/symfony-business-logic

Comment: I have about 30 columns in my tables, each have about 10-30 line of codes with html and "if", i can handle logic inside Model, but i cant handle html inside model.

Comment: What is in getEngineerData and getAdminData ?

Comment: it can be: set of checks(with queries to DB) what returning string or  instead of getEngineerData 8-10 html code with <?php ?> inserts

Comment: Your data must be set from model, you can perform some actions from the controller (set arrays for example) and add some HTML tags behind the view.

Comment: if I will perform all calls inside controller, i shoud create 30-40 useless variables(or indexes in second render() argument array to transfer into view. Then some time later code will be unreadable cuz, variables usage a far away from method calls.

Comment: It will be more readable and maintainable if you don't inject HTML code in model or controller !

Comment: html code not inside model, its inside VIEW. Did u see closing tags? <?php if (): ?>

Comment: html code just inside php templates

Comment: I think you may be confusing Model with Entity.  If you need a $model object as you described then write one.  The MVC police will probably not arrest you.  On the other hand, when moving from one framework to another it is often tempting to try and use concepts from the framework with which you are more familiar with.  It could be that your basic approach needs rethinking.

Comment: If your data is so different then why not just create a different template (View) for each user type? Do the logic in the Controller and select the appropriate View. If you are using the same set of <?php if ... ?> statements over and over, then that's your answer. If that doesn't work for you, then maybe just create various {% include file %} by user type in your twig template.